# IndexOutOfBoundsException post check

Tags: java, android, list

I am getting this exception:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsExceptionInvalid index 2, size is 0`

and bugsnag reports the line to be `RouteActivity.java:96us.example.serviceapp.tab.RouteActivity$2.handleMessage`

The crazy thing is a I have 2 spots that check against the list's `size()` method that should prevent that from occuring

```
    progressbar.setProgress(0);
    if (datalist.size() > 0) {
        float all = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < datalist.size(); i++) {
            all += datalist.get(i).getCompletionRate(); //line 96
        }

        progressbar.setProgress(Math.round(all / datalist.size()));
    }
    progressbar.refreshDrawableState();
```

So I understand that `i` was 2, and line 96 was `all += datalist.get(2).getCompletionRate();` and the error message says `datalist` size was 0. 
However what I don't understand is why the first check `datalist.size() > 0` evaluated to true and and even how i could become = 2 if the size was 0. And I'm also assuming that `datalist.get(1)` was called without a hitch on a previous iteration.  The model getCompletionRate method doesn't change the datalist.

```
public int getCompletionRate() {
    return total > 0 ? Math
            .round(((float) (total - remaining) / (float) total) * 100) : 0;
}
```

This is happening on an application that is live and it only happens to a small percentage of users. (1/100?) I don't know how to reproduce it and it really is baffling that it even is happening. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have a shared data structure across multiple threads. Another thread may be reseting the size of `datalist`, after your `datalist.size() > 0` validates.

Assuming this is the case, you will need to use mutex locks to avoid situations like this. Try looking into the [`synchronized` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Example:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

synchronized(lock) {
    if (datalist.size() > 0) {
        float all = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < datalist.size(); i++) {
            all += datalist.get(i).getCompletionRate(); //line 96
        }

        progressbar.setProgress(Math.round(all / datalist.size()));
    }
}
```

In the other location where you are presumably clearing out this data structure:

```
synchronized(lock) {
    datalist.clear();
}
```

This will ensure that `datalist` can never reset by another thread while you are iterating over it.

Comment: Looks good, I will need to deploy my new version and will follow up in a day. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if another thread is changing your datalist.

Answer (score 0):

The error which you are getting suggests that your datalist is a shared variable across multiple threads and is being changed by some other thread. You need to ensure that the part where you are calling `datalist.get(i)` should be called after checking the size of datalist and it should be an atomic operation for each thread.